# How to set Bundle Ids, App Identifiers and Provisioning Profiles to publish a WatchOs App made with SwiftUI and XCode?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchkit, provisioning-profile, watchos

I made a watchOS app with Xcode 12 and SwiftUI but I really struggle trying to publish it. An watchOS app has three pieces of code:

- the app
- the watchkit app
- the watchkit extension

I've tried to use the same bundle id for all (in the format: com.domain.appname). That failed. So I've tried to use a different bundle id for each as follow (knowing I've create the 3 App Identifiers and the 3 Provisioning Profiles matching those on developer.apple.com).

- the app (bundle id: com.domain.appname)
- the watchkit app (bundle id: com.domain.appname.watchkitapp)
- the watchkit extension (bundle id: com.domain.appname.watchkitextension)

This failed to build with this error:
[image]

So I cannot build or Archive my app. Then I've used the same bundleId for both App and Extension like this:

- the app (bundle id: com.domain.appname)
- the watchkit app (bundle id: com.domain.appname.watchkitapp)
- the watchkit extension (bundle id: com.domain.appname.watchkitapp)

With these settings I can build and archive the app. However when I try to upload it to the app store (with XCode or with the external app called the transporter) I got this error:

[image]

So at this point I'm lost... Is there someone here who has been able to publish a watch os app using swift UI and Xcode and who can tell me how to use Bundle Ids, App Identifiers and Provisioning Profiles to do so. Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @loremipsum yes it's as you said. You need to create 3 provisioning profiles. And the extension is  com.domain.appName.watchkitapp.watchkitextension Thanks for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Target > General > Bundle Indentifier

They should be incremental for the extension targets

- Main app = com.domain.appName
- Watch app = com.domain.appName.watchkitapp
- Watch extension = com.domain.appName.watchkitapp.watchkitextension

Your extension isn't unique (it doesn't add the extension part) from what I can see.

Also, your `Version` and `Build` in the same area should match all 3 Projects