# WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions whose WKAppBundleIdentifier matches

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-6

here is the error code I get

```
WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions whose WKAppBundleIdentifier matches "com.rshelver.tallyCounter.watchkitapp". Verify that the value of WKAppBundleIdentifier in your WatchKit Extension's Info.plist matches the value of CFBundleIdentifier in your WatchKit App's Info.plist.
```

Sorry I don't know a ton about Swift atm, I'm really new and I'm just looking to

Comment: The error gives specific instructions: "Verify that the value of WKAppBundleIdentifier in your WatchKit Extension's Info.plist matches the value of CFBundleIdentifier in your WatchKit App's Info.plist." Have you done this?

Comment: I'm aware. I haven't been able to find CFBundleIdentifier. I went through all the .plist files and it doesn't exist

Comment: If you're looking at it in Xcode, it normally shows the human-readable keys, not the true underlying keys. Do you see "Bundle Identifier"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984050/how-to-set-bundle-ids-app-identifiers-and-provisioning-profiles-to-publish-a-wa/66985435#66985435

Comment: @jnpdx yeah! all of them are the way they should be when building a watchOS app

Comment: Hmm. Well, Xcode doesn't think so. If you're convinced there are no differences (including case sensitivity) I'd probably to a 'clean' and then try building again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer: In the info plist for both the watch extension and the watch app they need to adhere to the following changes like this example

https://github.com/gabrieloc/GIOVANNI/issues/11