# WCSession counterpart app not installed or installed throughout settings in the watch app

Tags: swift, xcode, watch, wcsession

I have developed my watch app for my iOS App. The problem is that I need to use WCSession logic in order to send data from iOS to the AppWatch and vice versa.

If I install from Xcode, I get "WCSession counterpart app not installed" error message, so I wanted to install it throughout the settings view in the watch app but it does NOT appear here.

So how can I get my watch App appears there?

Comment: 1. Make sure the main app has the watch version included as a companion. 2. The bundles have to be named in a certain way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984050/how-to-set-bundle-ids-app-identifiers-and-provisioning-profiles-to-publish-a-wa/66985435#66985435 We can't help much more without knowing more.